# INSERT text from one table into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty sure I did this right, but my query has been running for half an hour now on a MySQL database on a regular laptop. The "tweets" table is only 1 million records big.

What do I want? Consider table "AAA" (left) and "BBB" (right)

```
id_str  text    id_str  text
------------    -------------------
13              13      foo bar baz
14              14      foobar
                13      foo bar baz
                17      foobaz
```

I want to fill the "text" column of table A with the text from table B:

```
UPDATE AAA
SET `text` = (
    SELECT `text` AS `text`
    FROM BBB
    WHERE id_str = AAA.id_str
    LIMIT 1
)
```

So that table AAA would look like

```
id_str  text
-------------------
13      foo bar baz
14      foobar
```

However, as said, this query is running far too long. Did I make a mistake in its syntax?

Comment: one way of doing this could be selecting values AS `text` then inserting in table B using `text` as the values that are inserted

Comment: Can `AAA` possibly contain rows that have no matches in `BBB`? If so, do you want to make sure that ```text``` values in those rows are empty?

Comment: It is not possible that AAA contains str_id's that have no matches in BBB. On the contrary - as the example shows, BBB can contain duplicate recordsets with the same str_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, this should be much faster:

```
UPDATE `AAA`,`BBB` SET `AAA`.`text`=`BBB`.`text`
WHERE `AAA`.`id_str`=`BBB`.`id_str`
```

You should only have to run this query once. It may still take a few minutes, but doing it this way (with a JOIN) is still probably going to be a lot faster than running 1 million separate queries.

`AAA`.`id_str` and `BBB`.`id_str` should both be indexed and preferably of the same data type, e.g. both should be int(11). This allows MySQL to evaluate the equality relationship between them with maximum efficiency.

EDIT: As I said, the query outlined above may still take some time, depending on your system configuration and your hardware (the operation could be disk-bound, i.e. limited by the speed of your hard disk). It could also be because MySQL is having to update indexes in table `AAA` - could you show us a `CREATE TABLE` statement for table `AAA`? Alternatively, you could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `CCC` LIKE `AAA`;
INSERT INTO `CCC` SELECT `AAA`.`str_id`,`BBB`.`text` FROM `AAA` JOIN `BBB` ON `AAA`.`id` = `BBB`.`id`;
```

This doesn't copy in any data from the old table `AAA`, though.

Comment: I'm running this query now, taken into consideration your tips, but it still already takes about 15 minutes now. Could the problem be that there are duplicate entries in BBB for the same id_str (see example in opening post)?

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem...how's performance for what I've just edited into my answer?

Comment: My bad - I spoke too soon. I forgot to put an index on AAA.str_id. After I did, the query finished in like 20 seconds! Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for letting us know you've found the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE AAA, BBB
SET AAA.`text` = BBB.text
WHERE BBB.id_str = AAA.id_str
```